# Electric Field of Superposition of Line Charges to Form an Equilateral Triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, superposition

Question: If three line charges with charge densities $\rho_1 = -2\rho_2= -2\rho_3$, and all length $L$ form an equilateral triangle, what is the force felt by a charge $Q$ at the center of the triangle?

Solution Attempt, and Specific Question:

In solving this question I noticed that all three line charges must be an equal perpendicular distance from the center, so maybe by superposition I could reduce the problem to an equivalent single line charge with density some fraction of $\rho_1$. My specific question is whether $\rho_2$ and $\rho_3$ exactly cancel off $\rho_1$ so no force is felt by the charge.

My reasoning for why an exact cancellation should occur is that if we consider not the electric field but the electric potential then the total potential is just a sum of scalar quantities. The electric potential along the perpendicular bisector of a line charge is dependent on the length of the line charge and the distance along the bisector. But line charges are all at an equal distance along their bisectors so the total potential is proportional to $$\rho_1(something) -\rho_1/2(something) -\rho_1/2(something)$$ which equals $$(\rho_1 -\rho_1/2 -\rho_1/2)(something)$$ = $$0$$.

The potential is $0$ so the field and hence the force must be $0$.

Comment: Those fields will not cancel in the center: the problem has a quantized rotation symmetry: the only way for those fields to cancel is if the charge densities are equal anything else will result in a net field in the center. Above the center of a line charge only the perpendicular field components are non vanishing.  For an equilateral triangle those field components only differ in $\rho_i$ in the coordinate system of all three lines. Adding the fields together in one coordinate system is rather easy geometrically or analytically.

Comment: Your "specific question" amounts to "is my answer (net force = $0$) correct?"

Comment: I think your statement of the charge densities is ambiguous. Does it mean that the charge on side 1 is +ve while those on side 2 & 3 are -ve, or that the charge on side 1 is -ve while those on sides 2 & 3 are +ve? Which you use affects the direction (but not the magnitude) of the force. But perhaps you are only asked for the magnitude of the force, not its direction.

Comment: You can reduce the problem to a single line charge (twice the net force from one segment), but the answer is not 0. The p_1 associated force has a vector in some direction that will be additive to the force from the oppositely charged segments across from it. As I read the problem, neither the potential nor the force will be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a charged equilateral triangle with the same uniform charge density along each side.
The net electric field at the centre of the triangle would be zero but the potential would not if the zero of potential is taken to be at infinity.
Imagine bringing a unit positive test charge coming from from infinity to the centre of the triangle.
An external force would have to do work (positive if the charge density is positive and negative if the charge density is negative) in moving from infinity to the centre of the triangle and hence the potential at that point is non zero.
I think the confusion might arise because the electric field is equal to minus the potential **gradient**.
Zero electric field means that the potential **gradient** is zero so the potential is a constant but not necessarily zero.

---

The changes on the three sides of the triangle are $\rho_1L, -\rho_2L$ and  $-\rho_3L$ which rewritten in terms of charge density $\rho_1$ are $\rho_1L, -\frac{\rho_1 L}{2}$ and  $-\frac{\rho_1L}{2}$.
If all the changes were $-\frac{\rho_1L}{2}$ then by symmetry the electric field at the centre of the triangle would be zero.
You can use superposition by finding out what charge (density) needs to be added to $-\frac{\rho_1L}{2}$ to get $\rho_1L$.

All you then need to do is to find the electric field due to that added charge (density).

---

**Update** in response to some comments.

I have tried to show diagrammatically how superposition works for this example.
[image]

If the line of charge with line charge density $\rho_1$ produces an electric field of magnitude $E$ the a line of charge with half the line charge density pr4oduces an electric field of magnitude $\frac E 2$.

Diagram **1** shows the initial problem.

Diagram **2** shows the three equal line charges producing zero electric field.

Diagram **3** shows the electric field which must be added to the arrangement of changes in diagram **2** to produce the charges and electric fields in diagram **1**.

@DWin Your comment was correct.

Looking at diagram **1** and adding the electric field vectorially a resultant electric field of magnitude

$E + \frac E 2 \; \cos 60^\circ + \frac E 2 \; \cos 60^\circ = \frac{3E}{2}$

Comment: So the problem is equivalent to a single line charge of density $-3\rho_1/2$?

Comment: @DWin How did you get $2\rho_1$?

Comment: @Farcher p1 + sin(30*pi/180)*2*(1/2)*p1  ... ooops ... Now voting for John Doe's answer.

Comment: @Farcher Can you explain why the application of the superposition principle just amounts to finding the charge needed to make $\rho_1 $ become $-\frac{\rho_1}{2}$?

Comment: @JohnDoe I am sorry but in the penultimate sentence of my original answer I occidentally interchanged $\rho_1$ and $-\frac{\rho_1}{2}$. I have now corrected that error.

Comment: @DWin I have updated my answer which shows that your analysis of the problem was correct.

Comment: @Farcher Thank you. Now the reasoning is very clear, and almost obvious.